# Pulling elements from a large string with PHP using CSS style selectors?

Tags: php, css, facebook, soap, css-selectors

I have the following long string returned from a SOAP call into a variable, and I need to find the contents of certain elements within it, namely the `.MoreInfoZone .OfferZone #Heading .content` and `.MoreInfoZone .OfferZone #Description .content`.

I can't do it with javascript, as it is for populating metatags for Facebook Open Graph, and their spiders won't run the javascript.

```
$soap = '    

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>


    <div class="MoreInfoZone">
      <div class="OfferZone">
        <div id="Heading" class="Group">
          <div class="Label">
            <h3>Activity</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Content">5-16 Trampoline / Swim Group 5-16 Trampoline / Swim
          Group5-16 Trampoline / Swim Group5-16 Trampolin1</div>
        </div>
        <div id="WhenZone">
          <div id="Date" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>
                <span class="StartDateLabel">Date</span>
              </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">
            <span class="Start Date">21 December 2010</span> to 
            <span class="End Date">24 November 2011</span></div>
          </div>
          <div id="Time" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Time</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">
            <span class="Start Time">10:00am</span> to 
            <span class="End Time">12:00am</span></div>
          </div>
          <div id="DaysOfTheWeek" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>
                <span class="DaysOfTheWeekLabel">Days</span>
              </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">
            <span class="weekdays">Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday,</span> 
            <span class="weekend">Saturday, Sunday</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Description" class="Group">
          <div class="Label">
            <h3>Description</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Content">
            <p>Trampolining5-16 Trampoline / Swim Group 5-16 Trampoline / Swim Group5-16
            Trampoline / Swim Group5-16 Trampolin15-16 Trampoline / Swim Group 5-16
            Trampoline / Swim Group5-16 Trampoline / Swim Group5-16 Trampolin15-16
            Trampoline / Swim Group 5-16 Trampoline / Swim Group5-16 Trampoline / Swim
            Group5-16 Trampolin15-16 Trampoline / Swim Group 5-16 Trampoline / Swim
            Group5-16 Trampoline / Swim Group5-16 Trampolin15-16 Trampoline / Swim Group
            5-16 Trampoline / Swim Group5-16 Trampoline / Swim Group5-16 Trampolin1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Provider" class="Group">
          <div class="Label">
            <h3>Provider</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Content">
          ProviderXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1</div>
        </div>
        <div id="Venue" class="Group">
          <div class="Label">
            <h3>Venue</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Content">Brimble Hill School, Tadpole Lane, RedhouseBrimble Hill
          School, Tadpole Lane, RedhouseBrimble Hill 1
          <br />SN25 2NB</div>
        </div>
        <div id="Ages" class="Group">
          <div class="Label">
            <h3>Ages</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Content">
          <span class="AgeFrom">5</span> to 
          <span class="AgeTo">16</span></div>
        </div>
        <div id="OpenTo" class="Group">
          <div class="Label">
            <h3>Open To</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Content">All disabled young people aged 5-16, and their friends,
          siblings, relatives.</div>
        </div>
        <div id="InclusiveAccessible" class="Group">
          <div class="Label">
            <h3>Inclusive/accessible for disabled users?</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Content">Yes</div>
        </div>
        <div id="SuitableForOlderPeople" class="Group">
          <div class="Label">
            <h3>Suitable for older people?</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Content">No</div>
        </div>
        <div id="Cost" class="Group">
          <div class="Label">
            <h3>Cost</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Content Free">Free unless xyzxyz</div>
        </div>
        <div id="DiscountAvailable" class="Group">
          <div class="Label">
            <h3>Discount/Leisure cards accepted?</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Content">Free unless xyzxyz</div>
        </div>
        <div id="MoreInformation" class="Group">
          <div class="Label">
            <h3>More information</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="Content">High demand, must book in advance.</div>
        </div>
        <div id="ContactZone" class="Group">
          <div class="Label">
            <h3>Contact</h3>
          </div>
          <div id="ContactName" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Contact Name</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">Ben HumphreyBen HumphreyBen HumphreyBen HumphreyBen
            HumphreyBen HumphreyBen HumphreyBen HumphreyBen</div>
          </div>
          <div id="ContactTel" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Contact Telephone</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">01793 617782 / mobile xxxxx xxxxxx 01793 617782 01793
            617782 / mobile xxxxx xxxxxx 01793 617782 0179</div>
          </div>
          <div id="ContactEmail" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Contact Email</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">
              <a href="mailto:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@swindon.gov.uk">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@swindon.gov.uk</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="ContactWebsite" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Contact Website</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">
              <a href="http://www.ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.gov.uk">www.ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.gov.uk</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="SafetyZone">
          <div class="Title">
            <h2>Safety</h2>
          </div>
          <div id="EnhancedCRB" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Enhanced CRB disclosure gained</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">All Staff</div>
          </div>
          <div id="ChildProtectionTrained" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Child Protection trained</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">Some Staff</div>
          </div>
          <div id="SafeguardingPolicy" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Organisation has safeguarding policy</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">Yes</div>
          </div>
          <div id="FirstAidOnSite" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>First Aid available on site</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="AccreditationInsurance" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Accreditation / Insurance</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">Yes</div>
          </div>
          <div id="SaferRecruitment" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>A member of staff on each recruitment panel trained in Safer
              Recruitment</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">Yes</div>
          </div>
          <div id="RegisteredWithIC" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Organisation registered with the Information Commissioner</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">Yes</div>
          </div>
          <div id="ExtraSafeguardingInfo" class="Group">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Additional Notes on Safeguarding</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">more info ....................</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ReviewSummaryZone">
          <div id="RSHeading">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Average rating</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">
              <img src="images/1Star.gif" alt="1 Star Rating" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="RSRating">
            <div class="Label">
              <h3>Number of ratings</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="Content">1 rating(s)</div>
          </div>
          <div id="RSNewReview">
            <div class="Content">
              <a href="?Type=CDA1C2A0-0BDC-47FD-B08D-BEDF8A6006DB&amp;Id=CC9488C5-C9A3-4A06-9A13-2BB9A1703157">
              Rate this</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ReviewZone">
          <div class="Review">
            <div class="User">
              <div class="Label">
                <h3>Name</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="Content">Gary Salter</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ReviewDate">
              <div class="Label">
                <h3>Date</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="Content">17 February 2011</div>
            </div>
            <div class="Comment">
              <div class="Label">
                <h3>Comments</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="Content">Test feedback</div>
            </div>
            <div class="Rating">
              <div class="Label">
                <h3>Rating</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="Content">
                <img src="images/1Star.gif" alt="1 Star Rating" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> ';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

or

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

An XPath example could be:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($soap);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// .MoreInfoZone .OfferZone #Heading .content
$headingContent = $xpath->query('//*[@id="Heading"]//*[contains(@class, "Content")]')->item(0);
if ($headingContent instanceof DOMNode) {
    echo $headingContent->nodeValue;
}

// .MoreInfoZone .OfferZone #Description .content
$descriptionContent = $xpath->query('//*[@id="Description"]//*[contains(@class, "Content")]/p')->item(0);
if ($descriptionContent instanceof DOMNode) {
    echo $descriptionContent->nodeValue;
}
```

as I normally only do stuff like this with xpath, I can't provide a working example with phpquery. Sorry about that.

Comment: I've added an xpath example, hope it's helpfull.

Comment: Feels like I am almost there, but gettint -- Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content in Entity -- Warning now, with no output.

Comment: Hmm, that's hard to debug from here. Are you sure the value of `$soap` is utf-16 encoded? Maybe there is an encoding problem while receiving the contents for this variable? If all fails, try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: Fixed it by adding `$soap = str_replace("utf-16","utf-8",$soap);`

Comment: One last thing, how could edit the description code to just get the first <p> tag?

Comment: See the updated example (added `/p` at the end of the query). This should select only `p`s and with the `->item(0)` you'll get the first one.