# Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content in Entity PHP error

Tags: php, character-encoding

I recently transferred my site to PHP5.3 from PHP5.2. I had in place an authentication module which was working fine earlier but now gives the error

```
Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content in Entity
```

I have tried replacing all occurrences of UTF-8 with UTF-16 but that did not help. What could be the possible solutions / causes of this error?

Comment: Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028685/pulling-elements-from-a-large-string-with-php-using-css-style-selectors/6028785#6028785 (see comments).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this:

http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/document-labelled-utf-16-but-has-utf-8-content-694388.html

Solution from this link simply replaces encoding information in the XML code:

```
$xml = $result->GetWeatherResult;
$xml = preg_replace('/(<\?xml[^?]+?)utf-16/i', '$1utf-8', $xml);
```

Not a nice solution, but worked for OP.

Comment: Link-only posts are discouraged for various reasons; though the fact that the page doesn't seem to be loading three years later is a good example of why.

Comment: You're right... apart from the fact that site loads perfectly. NVM, updated my answer to contain solution from mentioned link.

Comment: Sorry, at the time I clicked it it was loading incredibly slowly and I thought the website might have gone down or been deleted, on account of time.

Comment: this solution worked well for me, though does this kind of style do not produce negative effects in the xml result? is there a more accurate way to do this?