# xml is not valid - error 1002

Tags: php, xml

I am struck by this error that I can't seem to resolve. I am getting an XML IS NOT VALID, error 1002.

I have checked certain xml validators online and they indicate xml is well formed. The xml is there to query an api but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<SERVICE_SEARCH_REQUEST>
    <VERSION_HISTORY>APPLICATION_NAME=AppName XML_FILE_NAME =XMLFileName LICENCE_KEY=xxx-3939-xxxx-xxxx-xxx TS_API_VERSION = TSAPIVersion>
        <XML_VERSION_NO>3.0</XML_VERSION_NO>
    </VERSION_HISTORY>
    <GEO_LOCATION_NAME>London</GEO_LOCATION_NAME>
    <START_DATE>12 Jan 16</START_DATE>
    <NUMBER_OF_NIGHTS>1</NUMBER_OF_NIGHTS>
    <AVAILABLE_ONLY>TRUE</AVAILABLE_ONLY>
    <GET_START_PRICE>true</GET_START_PRICE>
    <ROOM_REPLY>
        <ANY_ROOM/>
    </ROOM_REPLY>
    <ROOMS_REQUIRED>
        <ROOM>
            <OCCUPANCY>2</OCCUPANCY>
            <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
        </ROOM>
        <ROOM>
            <OCCUPANCY>3</OCCUPANCY>
            <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
        </ROOM>
    </ROOMS_REQUIRED>
</SERVICE_SEARCH_REQUEST>
```

response i'm getting is:

```
Array ( [@attributes] => Array ( [CATEGORY] => XML Validation ) [VERSION_HISTORY] => Array ( [@attributes] => Array ( [APPLICATION_NAME] => AppName [XML_FILE_NAME] => XMLFileName [LICENCE_KEY] => LicenceKey [TS_API_VERSION] => TSAPIVersion ) [XML_VERSION_NO] => XMLVersionNumber ) [ERROR_NUMBER] => 1002 [ERROR_DESC] => XML is not valid )
```

updated php usage:

```
$header[] = "Accept: application/xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,5);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$XML);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = simplexml_load_string($response);
//$desired_array = json_decode(json_encode((array);



print_r($response);
?>
```

updated error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content on line 36
>   Warning: simplexml_load_string(): `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><SERVICE_SEARCH_RESPONSE><VERSION_HISTORY`  on line 36
>   Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  on line 36

Comment: That leads to following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'AppName' (T_STRING) on line 5. That's why I thought maybe PHP has to do with it.

Comment: Posted an an answer below take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
<VERSION_HISTORY>APPLICATION_NAME=AppName XML_FILE_NAME =XMLFileName LICENCE_KEY=xxx-3939-xxxx-xxxx-xxx TS_API_VERSION = TSAPIVersion>
```

is not valid XML. The `>` is not closing an element. You probably want those values as attributes. Try:

```
<VERSION_HISTORY APPLICATION_NAME=\"AppName\" XML_FILE_NAME =\"XMLFileName\" LICENCE_KEY=\"xxx-3939-xxxx-xxxx-xxx\" TS_API_VERSION = \"TSAPIVersion\">
```

Per your update I've escaped the double quotes here because it sounds like you are using those for the string encapsulation in PHP. Alternatively you could use single quotes.

```
<VERSION_HISTORY APPLICATION_NAME='AppName' XML_FILE_NAME ='XMLFileName' LICENCE_KEY='xxx-3939-xxxx-xxxx-xxx' TS_API_VERSION = 'TSAPIVersion'>
```

In both cases PHP used such as

```
$xml = "<VERSION_HISTORY APPLICATION_NAME='AppName' XML_FILE_NAME ='XMLFileName' LICENCE_KEY='xxx-3939-xxxx-xxxx-xxx' TS_API_VERSION = 'TSAPIVersion'>";
```

or

```
$xml = "<VERSION_HISTORY APPLICATION_NAME=\"AppName\" XML_FILE_NAME =\"XMLFileName\" LICENCE_KEY=\"xxx-3939-xxxx-xxxx-xxx\" TS_API_VERSION = \"TSAPIVersion\">";
```

should be valid.

Comment: Tried your method but still getting the xml not valid error.

Comment: Can you update your question to show your PHP usage?

Comment: I have removed &xml after xml= on your advise which seems to solve the problem.... However, now I am getting this error. Would you know how I can solve it? 
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content  line 36

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><SERVICE_SEARCH_RESPONSE><VERSION_HISTORY in  on line 36

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in p on line 36

Comment: Your question doesn't show the PHP usage nor where the `SERVICE_SEARCH_RESPONSE` is used. Please update your question.

Comment: It sounds like the data being returned from your API is formed incorrectly. You could take a look at this thread for that issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284548/document-labelled-utf-16-but-has-utf-8-content-in-entity-php-error. This answer resolves the issue your question was addressing though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99653/discussion-between-mush-and-chris85).